# is it a bug in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
create table Mytable1
(ID int,
Fname varchar(50)
)

create table Mytable2
(ID int,
Lname varchar(50)
)

insert into Mytable1 (ID,Fname)
values (1,'you')
insert into Mytable1 (ID,Fname)
values (2,'Tou')
insert into Mytable1 (ID,Fname)
values (3,'Nou')

insert into Mytable2 (ID,Lname)
values (1,'you2')
```

The field `Fname` does not exist in table `Mytable2` But we have a result for the following query :

```
select * from Mytable1 where Fname in (select Fname from Mytable2)
```

Note : I use sql server 2008 the result is all rows of table Mytable1

is it a bug in SQL ?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using?

Comment: The result would be coming as a blank row?

Comment: I can reproduce this in MySQL. That is spooky.

Comment: I use sql servser 2008 the result is all rows of table Mytable1

Comment: I think that puts the * content of MyTable1 to the Fname(you don't have primary key that so it makes it as a name of new array of MyTable2) and then show you the results as content of Fname of MyTable2 which contains the * of MyTable1.

Comment: Great question by the way. This is one of the reasons I like SO - I never heard of that behavior before.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - Sure. And the OP is asking _why_ is that happening. The OP is expecting an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.

You can see what's happening a bit clearer if you add table aliases to the fields used throughout the query:

```
select * from Mytable1 mt1 
where mt1.Fname in (select mt1.Fname from Mytable2 mt2)
```

- ie. the subquery is referencing (and returning) values from the main query.

If you change the query to:

```
select * from Mytable1 mt1 
where mt1.Fname in (select mt2.Fname from Mytable2 mt2)
```

- you get an error.

(SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77a67/7))

Comment: Thank you,
but anyway i think this is a source of ambiguity.

Comment: @MazenKhoder: Without being able to refer to columns from the main query inside the subquery, correlated sub-queries are impossible. The only ambiquity comes from not including the name/alias of the table with the column name.

Comment: so ,shouldn't the sql warn me about this ambiguity ?

Comment: @MazenKhoder: No - as far as the RDBMS is concerned, there is no ambiguity, since Fname only exists on Mytable1.

Comment: No, if you add the field Fname to the table Mytable2 (so we have now the field Fname  in the 2 tables) the sql don't give any ambiguity ? !
I think the engine firstly find the field in subquery if he didn't find it the sql try in the main query ?

Comment: @MazenKhoder: That's a different scenario - it may vary between RDBMSs, but the latter case is not being treated as a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26801

Apparently, this references `Fname` from `Mytable1`:

```
mysql> select *, (select Lname from Mytable1 limit 1) from Mytable2 where Lname in (select Lname from Mytable1 );
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| ID   | Lname | (select Lname from Mytable1 limit 1) |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
|    1 | you2  | you2                                 |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - Doesn't matter. It also applies for SQL Server.

Comment: Shouldn't matter as it seems to be an SQL standard thing.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal modify your query as `select * 
from Mytable1 AS t1
where t1.Fname in (select t2.Fname 
                from Mytable2 AS t2)` and it will give error

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - Well, that's the question the OP is asking. Why is there no error...